# CSS Z Index For Unity WebGL Build

Tags: css, visual-studio, webgl

so im trying to have a custom image and loading bar in my Unity WebGL build, i have changed the images in the folder and that works however my icon image takes up most of the background but is appearing in front of the progress bar.

I have tried doing this but it doesn't change the stacking order

```
#unity-logo { width: 1000px; height: 1000px; z-index: -1;background: url('unity-logo-dark.png') no-repeat center }
#unity-progress-bar-empty { width: 141px; height: 18px; z-index: -2; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 6.5px; background: url('progress-bar-empty-dark.png') no-repeat center }
```

Trying to get Logo to be behind the progress bar

Answer (score 0):

The logo image is behind the progress bar image, you can try setting the z-index property of the progress bar element to a higher value than the logo element.

Try this:

```
#unity-logo {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: url('unity-logo-dark.png') no-repeat center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#unity-progress-bar-empty {
  width: 141px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 6.5px;
  background: url('progress-bar-empty-dark.png') no-repeat center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The logo image is given a position of absolute, which allows it to be positioned behind the progress bar. The z-index of the logo image is set to -1, which puts it behind all other elements on the page. The progress bar image is given a position of relative, which keeps it in the normal flow of the page. The z-index of the progress bar image is set to 1, which puts it in front of the logo image.

Adjust the position of the logo and progress bar elements as per your requirement.